# MQ Cluster's sender channels are going into retrying state and running state vice versa

Tags: cluster-computing, ibm-mq, channel

I have configured MQ Cluster channels and connections seems to be fine. I am able to send and receive messages throughout clusters. But after some time sender channels seems to go into retrying state, By checking the error logs, it displays this error:

```
11/27/19 11:15:26 - Process(24533.300) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(853e7f40b70e) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.0.3) QMgr(QMF03)
                    Time(2019-11-27T11:15:26.161Z)
                    RemoteHost(40.87.***.***)
                    CommentInsert1(40.87.***.***)
                    CommentInsert2(TCP/IP)
                    CommentInsert3(select() [TIMEOUT] 360 seconds)

AMQ9259E: Connection timed out from host '40.87.***.***'.

EXPLANATION:
A connection from host '40.87.***.***' over TCP/IP timed out.
ACTION:
The select() [TIMEOUT] 360 seconds call timed out. Check to see why data was
not received in the expected time. Correct the problem. Reconnect the channel,
or wait for a retrying channel to reconnect itself
```

Please help me out. 
Thanks!

Comment: What is the error on the remote qmgr.

Comment: Check with your networking team if there is a firewall between the 2 servers and if so, is there a firewall timeout value for a connection.  The firewall timeout value either needs to be removed or set to unlimited.

Comment: @JoshMc No error on remote qmgr.

Comment: Try setting the remote `CLUSRCVR` to have a shorter `HBINT`.  The default is 300 seconds which is 5 minutes.   Timeouts happen at 360 seconds.   Setting it to something shorter like 15 will help if something like a firewall is timing out the connection,  an additional benefit is that the local qmgr will notice sooner and retry the connection.   If HBINT is less than 60 the timeout will be 2xHBINT, in the case of 15 it will timeout at 30 seconds.

Comment: Issue seems to be resolved after shortening HBInt to 15 seconds, thanks for the help Roger and JoshMc. Will monitor servers for a while to ensure it' resolved.

Comment: Can you confirm that you see no error on the remote qmgr somewhere in the 6 minutes prior to the `AMQ9259E` error you recieve on the local qmgr.  There should be something.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `Heartbeat interval` property of `CLUSRCVR` to 15 did resolve the issue for me.